# Make a Playlist Dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf

```
    private Queue<Uri> playList = new Queue<Uri>();
```

`playList.Enqueue(new Uri(@"D:\media1"));`
`playList.Enqueue(new Uri(@"D:\media2"));`
`playList.Enqueue(new Uri(@"D:\media3"));`

Here I am making the playlist hard coded. But I want to populate the playList from a string array. How is it possible?

My string array is `string[] mylist=new string[3];`

```
mylist[0]=@"D:\media1;
mylist[1]=@"D:\media2;
mylist[2]=@"D:\media3;
```

I have done this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Length; i++)
        {
            playList.Enqueue(new Uri(mylist[i]));
            mediaelement.play();

        }
```

But it is only playing the last media.....

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces your problem, it's not possible to know what the correct answer to your question is. However, assuming your _"making the playlist hard coded"_ version of the code does what you want, I would say the only thing you've done wrong in the code above is that you call `mediaelement.play();` inside the loop, when in fact you should put that statement outside the brackets, after the loop. Improve your question if you need more help than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't actually have a playlist feature, but you can easily implement it yourself. Implement the [MediaEndedEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaendedevent(v=vs.110).aspx) to your `mediaElement` and play the next element in your string array. My xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="320*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaelement" Grid.RowSpan="1" LoadedBehavior="Manual" MediaEnded="mediaelement_MediaEnded"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Content="Next" Click="mediaelement_MediaEnded" Width="50" Height="25" Margin="5"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string[] mylist = new string[3];

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mylist[0] = @"D:\media1";
        mylist[1] = @"D:\media1";
        mylist[2] = @"D:\media1";
        mediaelement.Source = new Uri(mylist[0]);
        mediaelement.Play();
    }

    private void mediaelement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mylist.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Uri current = new Uri(mylist[i]);
            if (mediaelement.Source == current)
            {
                mediaelement.Source = new Uri(mylist[i + 1]);
                break;
            }
        }

        mediaelement.Play();
    }
}
```